# AutoDeploy a Laravel app from GitHub branch to AWS EC2 or Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to auto deploy a Laravel app from a Github branch into AWS EC2 or Elastic Beanstalk (Prefer) but I haven't found the right solution, one of the tutorials I have followed is the one bellow. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you in advance!

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-continuous-deployment-on-aws-with-aws-codepipeline-jenkins-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following steps

1. Setup Jenkins with Github plugin
2. [Install](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html) AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI
3. Create IAM user with Elastic Beanstalk deploying privileges and add the access keys to AWS CLI (if Jenkins run inside a EC2, instead of creating a user, you can create a Role with requird permission and attach to the EC2 instance)
4. In Jenkins project, clone the branch go to project directory and executive [eb deploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-started.html#ebcli3-basics-deploy) in a shell script to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk. (You can automate this with a build trigger when new code pushed to the branch)

Alternatively there are other approaches, for example

- [Blue/Green deployment with Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html)
- Deploy Gitbranch to [specific environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html).
- Using [AWS CodeStar](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-codestar/) to setup the deployment using templates(Internally it will use AWS Code pipeline, CodeDeploy and etc.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `eb deploy` is to use the Jenkins AWS Beanstalk Publisher plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWS+Beanstalk+Publisher+Plugin

This can be installed by going to Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Search for AWS Beanstalk Publisher.  The root object is the zip file of the project that you want to deploy to EB.  The Build Steps can execute a step to zip up the files that are in your repo.

1. You will still need to fill in the `Source Control Management` section of the Jenkins Job configuration.  This must contain the URL of your GitHub repo, and the credentials used to access them.
2. Execute Shell as part of the Build Steps which zip up the files from the repo that you want to deploy to EB. For example `zip -r myfiles.zip *` will zip up all the files within your GitHub repo.
3. Use the AWS Beanstalk Publisher Plugin and specify `myfiles.zip` as the value of the Root Object (File / Directory).